# Enable proGuard Android

Tags: java, android, proguard

Hello everyone,
               I know the questions about proguard are already asked and answered. I go through some links. I am using Eclipse juno and ADT 19. Here is my sdk

```
     <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

What I want is someone give me a total walk through about how to enable ProGuard and also how to check weather it is enabled or not. I have very simple android project to test Proguard . Then I want to implement it on other application.
 My test application have a class called MainAvtivity and an xml file called activity main. 
SO far I havent find any help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You obviously did not used Google Search...

Comment: Tried it. But every link saying something different.

Comment: ProGuard is used since ages by thousands of people, including me. I found all I needed from Google or SO in minutes. It is as easy as one line to activate (literally), so keep looking please. At least tell us what you tried and found -- again, can't be nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add proguard-project.txt  to your project 
inside it you must set options you want form  progoard
for example i write these  options

> -optimizationpasses 5
>   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontpreverify
>   -verbose
>   -dontoptimize
>   -optimizations !code/simplification/arithetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

to  check  you can export your app to apk
an then  you can use dx2jar   to found if it is protected or not